# Primes of the form $q_n = p^n - 2$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Does this conjecture have a name ?

I assume it is true but has not been proven or disproven.

I am aware of prime twins, Dickson's conjecture, Bunyakovsky conjecture, Schinzel's hypothesis H, Bateman-Horn conjecture etc

See :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture

But this is a bit different ;

"mick's prime power conjecture"

Let $p$ be a prime.

Then there is always an integer $n$ such that

$q_n = p^n - 2$

and $q_n$ is also a prime.

---

Not important but for those who are curious,
My mentor believes the weaker conjecture what inspired me :

"tommy's prime power conjecture "

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p-2$ is also a prime.

Then there is always an integer $n>1$ such that

$q_n = p^n - 2$

and $q_n$ is also a prime.

This probably has no name.

---

Related is this sequence : primes $p$ such that $p^2 - 2$ is also prime.
So essentially the case $n = 2$.

https://oeis.org/A062326

and it starts like $2,3,5,7,13,19,29,37,43,47,61,...$

(this seems a bit biased towards the largest of prime twins for small primes, for those interested. It probably goes away for larger values. But it might relate to tommy's conjecture somewhat)

I note that there seem to be infinitely many primes of the form $2^m - 1$ (Mersenne) or $3^m - 2$.

Back to my conjecture :

Here are some examples listed by increasing primes and minimum value $n$ giving a prime :

$$2^2 - 2 = 2$$

$$3^2 - 2 = 7$$

$$5^1 - 2 = 3$$

$$7^1 - 2 = 5$$

$$11^4 - 2 = 14639$$

$$13^1 - 2 = 11$$

$$17^6 - 2 = 24137567$$

$$19 - 2 = 17$$

$$23^{24} - 2 = 480250763996501976790165756943039$$

$$29^2 - 2 = 839$$

$$31^1 - 2 = 29$$

$$37^2 - 2 = 1367$$

$$41^4 - 2 = 2825759$$
...

In fact we dare to make our conjectures stronger ; there are infinitely many $n$ for each prime $p$.

I (or we) are probably not the first to conjecture or observe this.
Hence I wonder if it has been named yet.
Any papers on it would be nice too ofcourse.

***edit***

A strange phenomenon but maybe just coincidence :

Due to the list above it seems we get all prime powers being of the form

$p^1 = p$ or $p^{2k}$

Why so many even powers ?

So I decided to extend the list :

$$43 - 2 = 41$$

$$ 47^2 - 2 = 2207$$

$$ 53^4 - 2 = 7890479$$

$$59^4 - 2 = 12117359$$

$$61^2 - 2 = 3719$$

$$67^3 - 2 = 300761$$

so finally the trend is broken at $67$.

An explaination I have not.

---

***edit 2***

I found these related sequences :

https://oeis.org/A240126

https://oeis.org/A257551

https://oeis.org/A160688

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150792/discussion-on-question-by-mick-primes-of-the-form-q-n-pn-2); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** This sequence and its comment section answer the present question: [OEIS sequence A267944](https://oeis.org/A267944). Thus, both the stated conjectures are very likely to be true (again, see the comments of $A267944$).

---

Now, an interesting additional sequence would be constructed by sorting in ascending numerical order the smallest values of ${p_n}^k-2$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ ($k:=k(p_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^+$).
Since every term of $a(n)$ such that $n>1$ has to be even, we get only the following candidates and we can easily check them one by one in a few minutes.
Here are the only sequences of the OEIS containing the subsequence $2,3,5,7,11,17,29$ and whose next term is an odd number: $A238528$, $A113192$, $A062294$, $A127272$, $A196375$, $A356627$.
Then, I verified that $a(8)=41$ and we know that $43$ cannot be a term since $45$ is not a prime. Moreover, the prime number $71$ is a term since $73$ is a prime, and consequently the only OEIS sequence that cannot easily be disregarded is $A238528(n):= 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 29, 41, 59, 71, 101, 107, 137, 149,\ldots$

Comment: Are you sure you got those OEIS numbers correct ? I got stuff I did not expect.
I upvoted for the first OEIS link what is certainly correct but the others are incorrect OR I am confused.  Please clarify

Comment: @mick I calculated the terms in my mind, just looking at the list of the first $100$ prime numbers. Now, the first part of my post answers to both of your questions, while the second part is about the only derived sequence that (IMHO) is worth to be submitted in the OEIS if and only if it is not the same as $A238528=2,3,5,7,11,17,29,41,59,71,101,107,137,\dots$.
The sequence, I am talking about can be obtained by sorting in ascending order the smallest values of ${p_1}^{n_1}-2,{p_2}^{n_2}-2,\dots$, where $p_j:j=1,2,3,\ldots$ are the primes (i.e., $p_1=2, p_2=3,  \dots$ and so forth).

Comment: Please, note that in the above I used $n_j$ to indicate the smallest positive integers such that ${p_j}^{n_j}$ is prime.

Comment: oh I see. That way. hmm